# Scripting SQL Server permissions

Tags: sql-server

I want to copy all the permission I've set on stored procedures and other stuff from my development database to my production database. It's incredibly cumbersome, not to mention error prone, to do this all by hand through the SSMS GUI tool.

So I'm looking for a way I can directly dump the permissions set in one database, and apply those same permissions to a separate database (presumably having the same schema).

Answer (score 101, accepted):

The database's built-in catalog views provide the information to do this. Try this query:

```
SELECT
  (
    dp.state_desc + ' ' +
    dp.permission_name collate latin1_general_cs_as + 
    ' ON ' + '[' + s.name + ']' + '.' + '[' + o.name + ']' +
    ' TO ' + '[' + dpr.name + ']'
  ) AS GRANT_STMT
FROM sys.database_permissions AS dp
  INNER JOIN sys.objects AS o ON dp.major_id=o.object_id
  INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s ON o.schema_id = s.schema_id
  INNER JOIN sys.database_principals AS dpr ON dp.grantee_principal_id=dpr.principal_id
WHERE dpr.name NOT IN ('public','guest')
--  AND o.name IN ('My_Procedure')      -- Uncomment to filter to specific object(s)
--  AND dp.permission_name='EXECUTE'    -- Uncomment to filter to just the EXECUTEs
```

This will spit out a bunch of commands (GRANT/DENY) for each of the permissions in the database. From this, you can copy-and-paste them into another query window and execute, to generate the same permissions that were in place on the original. For example:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON [Exposed].[EmployeePunchoutReservationRetrieve] TO [CustomerAgentRole]
GRANT EXECUTE ON [Exposed].[EmployeePunchoutReservationStore] TO [CustomerAgentRole]
GRANT EXECUTE ON [Exposed].[EmployeePunchoutSendOrderLogStore] TO [CustomerAgentRole]
GRANT EXECUTE ON [Exposed].[EmployeeReportSubscriptions] TO [CustomerAgentRole]
```

Note the bottom line, commented out, that's filtering on permission_name. Un-commenting that line will cause the query to only spit out the EXECUTE permissions (i.e., those for stored procedures).

Comment: This script turns DENY's into GRANTs. You need to change the `'GRANT '` part into `dp.state_desc + ' '`. Adding `QUOTENAME()` around s.name, o.name, and dpr.name would also help this script immensely.

Comment: Awesome query, this has generate all the permissions I needed, I just had to add a where clause to limit it to the schema I wanted and bam. Awesome script.

Comment: This script will miss when you grant or deny an entire DML operation on a database e.g. GRANT SELECT TO [USerName]

Comment: @Matt Had the same issue so modified slightly in answer below https://stackoverflow.com/a/47906612/275388

Comment: This accepted answer did not work for me at all.  The one from @MadsRavn and matt works for me.

Comment: For some reason this excludes 3 of my 5 schemas, including dbo.  I can't figure out why they are missing.  Otherwise a great solution.  May be something with the principals?

Comment: Follow-up: some schemas weren't appearing for me, apparently because they were owned by one of the db roles.  Since the role owns the schema, there is no need to explicitly grant select, etc.

Answer (score 69):

You can get SQL Server Management Studio to do it for you:

- Right click the database you want to export permissions for
- Select 'Tasks' then 'Generate Scripts...'
- Confirm the database you're scripting
- Set the following scripting options:

  - Script Create: FALSE
  - Script Object-Level Permissions: TRUE
- Select the object types whose permission you want to script
- Select the objects whose permission you want to script
- Select where you want the script produced

This will produce a script to set permissions for all selected objects but suppresses the object scripts themselves.

*This is based on the dialog for MS SQL 2008 with all other scripting options unchanged from install defaults.*

Comment: This actually seems to be the best answer, despite the lack of upvotes.

Comment: The defaults for the options in step 4 can be changed by opening Tools - Options - SQL Server Object Explorer - Scripting.

Comment: This is what I have done but it includes too much, it generates the tables, or sprocs and stuff i purely wanted the permissions and cannot seem to isolate just permissions with the tasks :/

Comment: This was based on SQL 2008, if you're using a newer version you may need to use one of the scripting approaches as it look like they've removed this option from the dialog. I've just tried in 2012 and it now forces you to generate the Create statements.

If you are using 2008 just double check you set "Script Create" to FALSE as this will suppress the actual object scripts.

Comment: @PeteWiFi; I cannot get this to work with the new SSMS (version 17.9.1). Do you know if it is still possible?

Comment: My options don't allow script Create: False.  My options are Script Create, Script Drop, or Script Drop and Create.  Thus, I can only generate scripts that include the permissions AND the creation of all the objects, which is not what I want.  Using SSMS 17.9.1

Answer (score 18):

Expanding on [the answer provided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1987215/1501497) which fails for database/schema wide rights and database user types you can use:

```
SELECT
  CASE
      WHEN dp.class_desc = 'OBJECT_OR_COLUMN' THEN
        dp.state_desc + ' ' + dp.permission_name collate latin1_general_cs_as + 
        ' ON ' + '[' + obj_sch.name + ']' + '.' + '[' + o.name + ']' +
        ' TO ' + '[' + dpr.name + ']'
      WHEN dp.class_desc = 'DATABASE' THEN
        dp.state_desc + ' ' + dp.permission_name collate latin1_general_cs_as + 
        ' TO ' + '[' + dpr.name + ']'
      WHEN dp.class_desc = 'SCHEMA' THEN
        dp.state_desc + ' ' + dp.permission_name collate latin1_general_cs_as + 
        ' ON SCHEMA :: ' + '[' + SCHEMA_NAME(dp.major_id) + ']' +
        ' TO ' + '[' + dpr.name + ']'
      WHEN dp.class_desc = 'TYPE' THEN
        dp.state_desc + ' ' + dp.permission_name collate Latin1_General_CS_AS + 
        ' ON TYPE :: [' + s_types.name + '].[' + t.name + ']'
            + ' TO [' + dpr.name + ']'
      WHEN dp.class_desc = 'CERTIFICATE' THEN 
        dp.state_desc + ' ' + dp.permission_name collate latin1_general_cs_as + 
        ' TO ' + '[' + dpr.name + ']' 
      WHEN dp.class_desc = 'SYMMETRIC_KEYS' THEN 
        dp.state_desc + ' ' + dp.permission_name collate latin1_general_cs_as + 
      ' TO ' + '[' + dpr.name + ']' 
      ELSE 
        'ERROR: Unhandled class_desc: ' + dp.class_desc
  END
 AS GRANT_STMT
FROM sys.database_permissions AS dp 
  JOIN sys.database_principals AS dpr ON dp.grantee_principal_id=dpr.principal_id
  LEFT JOIN sys.objects AS o ON dp.major_id=o.object_id
  LEFT JOIN sys.schemas AS obj_sch ON o.schema_id = obj_sch.schema_id
  LEFT JOIN sys.types AS t ON dp.major_id = t.user_type_id
  LEFT JOIN sys.schemas AS s_types ON t.schema_id = s_types.schema_id
WHERE 
dpr.name NOT IN ('public','guest') 
--  AND o.name IN ('My_Procedure')      -- Uncomment to filter to specific object(s)
--  AND (o.name NOT IN ('My_Procedure') or o.name is null)  -- Uncomment to filter out specific object(s), but include rows with no o.name (VIEW DEFINITION etc.)
--  AND dp.permission_name='EXECUTE'    -- Uncomment to filter to just the EXECUTEs
--  AND dpr.name LIKE '%user_name%'     -- Uncomment to filter to just matching users
ORDER BY dpr.name, dp.class_desc, dp.permission_name
```

Comment: Schema level permissions grants will be in incorrect format:
`GRANT UPDATE ON SCHEMA [test] TO [TestUser]`

Instead of:

`GRANT UPDATE ON SCHEMA :: [test] TO [TestUser]`

Otherwise fantastic answer!

Comment: @Chris: Thanks updated the answer to generate correct sql.

Comment: One additional problem I encountered was that schema owner's were not transferred. A schema owner has full access over a table they own. To find existing schema owners:
`SELECT schema_name, schema_owner
FROM information_schema.schemata`

Then to assign those on your new database.

`ALTER AUTHORIZATION    
   ON SCHEMA::SCHEMA_NAME_HERE
   TO DB_USER_NAME_HERE` 

[Mirosoft's documentation on the syntax for ALTER AUTHORIZATION.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-authorization-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: @MadsRavn; I have a Certificate and a Symmetric Key as well, which causes an except, unless you add:       WHEN dp.class_desc = 'CERTIFICATE' THEN
        dp.state_desc + ' ' + dp.permission_name collate latin1_general_cs_as + 
        ' TO ' + '[' + dpr.name + ']'
      WHEN dp.class_desc = 'SYMMETRIC_KEYS' THEN
        dp.state_desc + ' ' + dp.permission_name collate latin1_general_cs_as + 
        ' TO ' + '[' + dpr.name + ']'

Comment: @Henrik Staun Poulsen Thanks - updated with your suggestions.

Comment: @MadsRavn; I've added a comment on how to exclude certain Stored Procedures, but leaving in VIEW DEFINITION statements. I just got bitten by NULLs (again)  :-)

Comment: @HenrikStaunPoulsen Cheers :)

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can use a script like this to generate another script

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @NewRole varchar(100), @SourceRole varchar(100);

-- Change as needed
SELECT @SourceRole = 'Giver', @NewRole = 'Taker';

SELECT
    state_desc + ' ' + permission_name + ' ON ' + OBJECT_NAME(major_id) + ' TO ' + @NewRole
FROM
    sys.database_permissions
WHERE
    grantee_principal_id = DATABASE_PRINCIPAL_ID(@SourceRole) AND
    -- 0 = DB,  1 = object/column, 3 = schema. 1 is normally enough
    class <= 3
```

[This is taken from my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372086/in-sql-server-2005-is-there-an-easy-way-to-copy-permissions-on-an-object-from/375782#375782)

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT
    dp.state_desc + ' ' 
       + dp.permission_name collate latin1_general_cs_as
       + ISNULL((' ON ' + QUOTENAME(s.name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(o.name)),'')
       + ' TO ' + QUOTENAME(dpr.name)
FROM sys.database_permissions AS dp
  LEFT JOIN sys.objects AS o ON dp.major_id=o.object_id
  LEFT JOIN sys.schemas AS s ON o.schema_id = s.schema_id
  LEFT JOIN sys.database_principals AS dpr ON dp.grantee_principal_id=dpr.principal_id
WHERE dpr.name NOT IN ('public','guest')
```

Slight change of the accepted answer if you want to grab permissions that are applied at database level in addition to object level.  Basically switch to `LEFT JOIN` and make sure to handle `NULL` for `object` and `schema` `names`.

Answer (score 2):

YOU CAN ALSO DOWNLOAD THE CODE IN THE BELOW LINK AND SEE HOW IT WORKS

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Extract-Database-dfa53d5a

[THIS IS HOW YOU WILL SEE THE OUTPUT OF THIS QUERY](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWHH8.jpg)

```
set nocount off

IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..##temp1') IS NOT NULL
     DROP TABLE ##temp1

create table ##temp1(query varchar(1000))

insert into ##temp1 
select 'use '+db_name() +';'

insert into ##temp1 
select 'go'

/*creating database roles*/
insert into ##temp1
                    select 'if DATABASE_PRINCIPAL_ID('''+name+''')  is null 
                    exec sp_addrole '''+name+''''  from sysusers
where issqlrole = 1 and (sid is not null and sid <> 0x0)

/*creating application roles*/
insert into ##temp1
                    select 'if DATABASE_PRINCIPAL_ID('+char(39)+name+char(39)+')
                    is null CREATE APPLICATION ROLE ['+name+'] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = ['+
                    default_schema_name+'], Password='+char(39)+'Pass$w0rd123'+char(39)+' ;'
 from sys.database_principals
where type_desc='APPLICATION_ROLE'

insert into ##temp1 
                     select  
                                case  
                                          when state_desc='GRANT_WITH_GRANT_OPTION' 
                                                       then
                                                                substring (state_desc,0,6)+' '+permission_name+' to '+'['+USER_NAME(grantee_principal_id)+']'+' WITH GRANT OPTION ;'

                                                         else 
                                                                  state_desc+' '+permission_name+' to '+'['+USER_NAME(grantee_principal_id)+']'+' ;'
                    END
from sys.database_permissions 
where class=0 and USER_NAME(grantee_principal_id) not in ('dbo','guest','sys','information_schema')

insert into ##temp1 
                    select 
                               case 
                                         when state_desc='GRANT_WITH_GRANT_OPTION' 
                                                   then
                                                             substring (state_desc,0,6)+' '+permission_name+' on '+OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(major_id)+'.['+OBJECT_NAME(major_id)
                                                             +'] to '+'['+USER_NAME(grantee_principal_id)+']'+' with grant option ;'
                                                     else 
                                                              state_desc+' '+permission_name+' on '+OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(major_id)+'.['+OBJECT_NAME(major_id)
                                                              +'] to '+'['+USER_NAME(grantee_principal_id)+']'+' ;'
                                  end
from sys.database_permissions where class=1 and USER_NAME(grantee_principal_id) not in ('public');


 insert into ##temp1 
                      select 
                                 case 
                                           when state_desc='GRANT_WITH_GRANT_OPTION' 
                                                     then
                                                              substring (state_desc,0,6)+' '+permission_name+' ON schema::['+sa.name+
                                                               '] to ['+user_name(dp.grantee_principal_id)+'] with grant option ;'
                                                       else
                                                               state_desc+' '+permission_name+' ON schema::['+sa.name+
                                                               '] to ['+user_name(dp.grantee_principal_id)+'] ;'
                                                       COLLATE LATIN1_General_CI_AS  
                                      end
from sys.database_permissions dp inner join sys.schemas sa on
 sa.schema_id = dp.major_id where dp.class=3

 insert into ##temp1 
                     select 
                                 case 
                                            when state_desc='GRANT_WITH_GRANT_OPTION'
                                             then
                                                    substring (state_desc,0,6)+' '+permission_name+' ON APPLICATION  ROLE::['+sa.name+
                                                     '] to ['+user_name(dp.grantee_principal_id)+'] with grant option ;'
                                             else
                                                      state_desc+' '+permission_name+' ON  APPLICATION ROLE::['+sa.name+
                                                      '] to ['+user_name(dp.grantee_principal_id)+'] ;'
                                                      COLLATE LATIN1_General_CI_AS  
                         end
from sys.database_permissions dp inner join sys.database_principals  sa on
 sa.principal_id = dp.major_id where dp.class=4 and sa.type='A'

 insert into ##temp1 
                      select 
                                 case 
                                          when state_desc='GRANT_WITH_GRANT_OPTION' 
                                           then
                                                  substring (state_desc,0,6)+' '+permission_name+' ON   ROLE::['+sa.name+
                                                  '] to ['+user_name(dp.grantee_principal_id)+'] with grant option ;'
                                           else
                                                   state_desc+' '+permission_name+' ON   ROLE::['+sa.name+
                                                    '] to ['+user_name(dp.grantee_principal_id)+'] ;'
                                                     COLLATE LATIN1_General_CI_AS  
                                           end
 from sys.database_permissions dp inner join
sys.database_principals  sa on sa.principal_id = dp.major_id 
 where dp.class=4 and sa.type='R'

 insert into ##temp1 
                      select 
                                  case 
                                           when state_desc='GRANT_WITH_GRANT_OPTION' 
                                                       then
                                                               substring (state_desc,0,6)+' '+permission_name+' ON ASSEMBLY::['+sa.name+
                                                                '] to ['+user_name(dp.grantee_principal_id)+'] with grant option ;'
                                                        else
                                                                state_desc+' '+permission_name+' ON ASSEMBLY::['+sa.name+
                                                                 '] to ['+user_name(dp.grantee_principal_id)+'] ;'
                                                                 COLLATE LATIN1_General_CI_AS  
                                       end
 from sys.database_permissions dp inner join sys.assemblies sa on
 sa.assembly_id = dp.major_id 
 where dp.class=5

 insert into ##temp1
                     select 
                                 case 
                                           when state_desc='GRANT_WITH_GRANT_OPTION' 
                                            then
                                                    substring (state_desc,0,6)+'  '+permission_name+' ON type::['
                                                    +SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id)+'].['+sa.name+
                                                    '] to ['+user_name(dp.grantee_principal_id)+'] with grant option ;'
                                            else
                                                    state_desc+' '+permission_name+' ON type::['
                                                    +SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id)+'].['+sa.name+
                                                     '] to ['+user_name(dp.grantee_principal_id)+'] ;'
                                                     COLLATE LATIN1_General_CI_AS  
                                              end
 from sys.database_permissions dp inner join sys.types sa on
 sa.user_type_id = dp.major_id 
 where dp.class=6


 insert into ##temp1
                      select 
                                 case 
                                          when state_desc='GRANT_WITH_GRANT_OPTION' 
                                           then
                                                     substring (state_desc,0,6)+'  '+permission_name+' ON  XML SCHEMA COLLECTION::['+
                                                     SCHEMA_NAME(SCHEMA_ID)+'].['+sa.name+'] to ['+user_name(dp.grantee_principal_id)+'] with grant option ;'
                                            else
                                                     state_desc+' '+permission_name+' ON  XML SCHEMA COLLECTION::['+
                                                     SCHEMA_NAME(SCHEMA_ID)+'].['+sa.name+'] to ['+user_name(dp.grantee_principal_id)+'];'
                                                     COLLATE LATIN1_General_CI_AS  
                                   end
 from sys.database_permissions dp inner join sys.xml_schema_collections sa on
 sa.xml_collection_id = dp.major_id 
 where dp.class=10



insert into ##temp1
                    select
                               case 
                                         when state_desc='GRANT_WITH_GRANT_OPTION' 
                                          then
                                                   substring (state_desc,0,6)+'  '+permission_name+' ON message type::['+sa.name+
                                                    '] to ['+user_name(dp.grantee_principal_id)+'] with grant option ;'
                                           else
                                                    state_desc+' '+permission_name+' ON message type::['+sa.name+
                                                    '] to ['+user_name(dp.grantee_principal_id)+'] ;'
                                                     COLLATE LATIN1_General_CI_AS  
                                             end
 from sys.database_permissions dp inner join sys.service_message_types sa on
 sa.message_type_id = dp.major_id 
 where dp.class=15


 insert into ##temp1
                      select 
                                  case 
                                            when state_desc='GRANT_WITH_GRANT_OPTION' 
                                              then
                                                       substring (state_desc,0,6)+'  '+permission_name+' ON contract::['+sa.name+
                                                        '] to ['+user_name(dp.grantee_principal_id)+'] with grant option ;'
                                                else
                                                         state_desc+' '+permission_name+' ON contract::['+sa.name+
                                                         '] to ['+user_name(dp.grantee_principal_id)+'] ;'
                                                         COLLATE LATIN1_General_CI_AS  
                                   end
 from sys.database_permissions dp inner join sys.service_contracts sa on
 sa.service_contract_id = dp.major_id 
 where dp.class=16



  insert into ##temp1
                      select 
                                 case 
                                           when state_desc='GRANT_WITH_GRANT_OPTION' 
                                            then
                                                      substring (state_desc,0,6)+'  '+permission_name+' ON SERVICE::['+sa.name+
                                                        '] to ['+user_name(dp.grantee_principal_id)+'] with grant option ;'
                                              else
                                                       state_desc+'  '+permission_name+' ON SERVICE::['+sa.name+
                                                        '] to ['+user_name(dp.grantee_principal_id)+'] ;'
                                                        COLLATE LATIN1_General_CI_AS  
                                    end
 from sys.database_permissions dp inner join sys.services sa on
 sa.service_id = dp.major_id 
 where dp.class=17


 insert into ##temp1 
                      select 
                                   case 
                                              when state_desc='GRANT_WITH_GRANT_OPTION'
                                               then
                                                          substring (state_desc,0,6)+'  '+permission_name+' ON REMOTE SERVICE BINDING::['+sa.name+
                                                          '] to ['+user_name(dp.grantee_principal_id)+'] with grant option ;'
                                                 else
                                                          state_desc+' '+permission_name+' ON REMOTE SERVICE BINDING::['+sa.name+
                                                           '] to ['+user_name(dp.grantee_principal_id)+'] ;'
                                                          COLLATE LATIN1_General_CI_AS  
                                      end
 from sys.database_permissions dp inner join sys.remote_service_bindings sa on
 sa.remote_service_binding_id = dp.major_id 
 where dp.class=18

 insert into ##temp1
                      select
                                  case 
                                            when state_desc='GRANT_WITH_GRANT_OPTION'
                                              then
                                                        substring (state_desc,0,6)+'  '+permission_name+' ON route::['+sa.name+
                                                        '] to ['+user_name(dp.grantee_principal_id)+'] with grant option ;'
                                                else
                                                          state_desc+' '+permission_name+' ON route::['+sa.name+
                                                          '] to ['+user_name(dp.grantee_principal_id)+'] ;'
                                                         COLLATE LATIN1_General_CI_AS  
                                      end
 from sys.database_permissions dp inner join sys.routes sa on
 sa.route_id = dp.major_id 
 where dp.class=19

 insert into ##temp1 
                      select 
                                 case 
                                           when state_desc='GRANT_WITH_GRANT_OPTION' 
                                            then
                                                     substring (state_desc,0,6)+'  '+permission_name+' ON FULLTEXT CATALOG::['+sa.name+
                                                      '] to ['+user_name(dp.grantee_principal_id)+'] with grant option ;'
                                             else
                                                       state_desc+' '+permission_name+' ON FULLTEXT CATALOG::['+sa.name+
                                                       '] to ['+user_name(dp.grantee_principal_id)+'] ;'
                                                        COLLATE LATIN1_General_CI_AS  
                                       end
 from sys.database_permissions dp inner join sys.fulltext_catalogs sa on
 sa.fulltext_catalog_id = dp.major_id 
 where dp.class=23

  insert into ##temp1 
                      select 
                                 case 
                                           when state_desc='GRANT_WITH_GRANT_OPTION'
                                            then
                                                        substring (state_desc,0,6)+'  '+permission_name+' ON SYMMETRIC KEY::['+sa.name+
                                                        '] to ['+user_name(dp.grantee_principal_id)+'] with grant option ;'
                                             else
                                                        state_desc+' '+permission_name+' ON SYMMETRIC KEY::['+sa.name+
                                                        '] to ['+user_name(dp.grantee_principal_id)+'] ;'
                                                        COLLATE LATIN1_General_CI_AS  
                                             end
 from sys.database_permissions dp inner join sys.symmetric_keys sa on
 sa.symmetric_key_id = dp.major_id 
 where dp.class=24

 insert into ##temp1 
                      select 
                                  case 
                                           when state_desc='GRANT_WITH_GRANT_OPTION' 
                                             then
                                                       substring (state_desc,0,6)+'  '+permission_name+' ON certificate::['+sa.name+
                                                        '] to ['+user_name(dp.grantee_principal_id)+'] with grant option ;'
                                               else
                                                          state_desc+' '+permission_name+' ON certificate::['+sa.name+
                                                          '] to ['+user_name(dp.grantee_principal_id)+'] ;'
                                                           COLLATE LATIN1_General_CI_AS  
                                   end
 from sys.database_permissions dp inner join sys.certificates sa on
 sa.certificate_id = dp.major_id 
 where dp.class=25


 insert into ##temp1 
                     select 
                                 case 
                                          when state_desc='GRANT_WITH_GRANT_OPTION' 
                                          then
                                                     substring (state_desc,0,6)+'  '+permission_name+' ON ASYMMETRIC KEY::['+sa.name+
                                                     '] to ['+user_name(dp.grantee_principal_id)+'] with grant option ;'
                                             else
                                                      state_desc+' '+permission_name+' ON ASYMMETRIC KEY::['+sa.name+
                                                       '] to ['+user_name(dp.grantee_principal_id)+'] ;'
                                                       COLLATE LATIN1_General_CI_AS  
                        end
 from sys.database_permissions dp inner join sys.asymmetric_keys sa on
 sa.asymmetric_key_id = dp.major_id 
 where dp.class=26

insert into ##temp1 
                     select  'exec sp_addrolemember ''' +p.NAME+''','+'['+m.NAME+']'+' ;'
FROM sys.database_role_members rm
JOIN sys.database_principals p
ON rm.role_principal_id = p.principal_id
JOIN sys.database_principals m
ON rm.member_principal_id = m.principal_id
where m.name not like 'dbo';






select *  from ##temp1
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Chris for [his awesome answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1987215/1501497), I took it one step further and automated the process of running those statements (my table had over 8,000 permissions)

```
if object_id('dbo.tempPermissions') is not null
Drop table dbo.tempPermissions

Create table tempPermissions(ID int identity , Queries Varchar(255))


Insert into tempPermissions(Queries)


select 'GRANT ' + dp.permission_name collate latin1_general_cs_as
   + ' ON ' + s.name + '.' + o.name + ' TO ' + dpr.name 
   FROM sys.database_permissions AS dp
   INNER JOIN sys.objects AS o ON dp.major_id=o.object_id
   INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s ON o.schema_id = s.schema_id
   INNER JOIN sys.database_principals AS dpr ON dp.grantee_principal_id=dpr.principal_id
   WHERE dpr.name NOT IN ('public','guest')

declare @count int, @max int, @query Varchar(255)
set @count =1
set @max = (Select max(ID) from tempPermissions)
set @query = (Select Queries from tempPermissions where ID = @count)

while(@count < @max)
begin
exec(@query)
set @count += 1
set @query = (Select Queries from tempPermissions where ID = @count)
end

select * from tempPermissions

drop table tempPermissions
```

additionally to restrict it to a single table add:

```
  and o.name = 'tablename'
```

after the WHERE dpr.name NOT IN ('public','guest')
and remember to edit the select statement so that it generates statements for the table you want to grant permissions 'TO' Not the table the permissions are coming 'FROM' (which is what the script does).

Answer (score 0):

Our version:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @message NVARCHAR(MAX)

-- GENERATE LOGINS CREATE SCRIPT


USE [master]

-- creating accessory procedure

IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM    sys.objects WHERE   object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'sp_hexadecimal') AND type IN ( N'P', N'PC' )) 
DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_hexadecimal]
EXEC('
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_hexadecimal]
    @binvalue varbinary(256),
    @hexvalue varchar (514) OUTPUT
AS
DECLARE @charvalue varchar (514)
DECLARE @i int
DECLARE @length int
DECLARE @hexstring char(16)
SELECT @charvalue = ''0x''
SELECT @i = 1
SELECT @length = DATALENGTH (@binvalue)
SELECT @hexstring = ''0123456789ABCDEF''
WHILE (@i <= @length)
BEGIN
  DECLARE @tempint int
  DECLARE @firstint int
  DECLARE @secondint int
  SELECT @tempint = CONVERT(int, SUBSTRING(@binvalue,@i,1))
  SELECT @firstint = FLOOR(@tempint/16)
  SELECT @secondint = @tempint - (@firstint*16)
  SELECT @charvalue = @charvalue +
    SUBSTRING(@hexstring, @firstint+1, 1) +
    SUBSTRING(@hexstring, @secondint+1, 1)
  SELECT @i = @i + 1
END

SELECT @hexvalue = @charvalue')

SET @message = '-- CREATE LOGINS' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(13) +'USE [master]' + CHAR(13)

DECLARE @name sysname
DECLARE @type varchar (1)
DECLARE @hasaccess int
DECLARE @denylogin int
DECLARE @is_disabled int
DECLARE @PWD_varbinary  varbinary (256)
DECLARE @PWD_string  varchar (514)
DECLARE @SID_varbinary varbinary (85)
DECLARE @SID_string varchar (514)
DECLARE @tmpstr  NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @is_policy_checked varchar (3)
DECLARE @is_expiration_checked varchar (3)

DECLARE @defaultdb sysname

DECLARE login_curs CURSOR FOR
      SELECT p.sid, p.name, p.type, p.is_disabled, p.default_database_name, l.hasaccess, l.denylogin FROM 
sys.server_principals p LEFT JOIN sys.syslogins l
      ON ( l.name = p.name ) WHERE p.type IN ( 'S', 'G', 'U' ) AND p.name <> 'sa'

OPEN login_curs

FETCH NEXT FROM login_curs INTO @SID_varbinary, @name, @type, @is_disabled, @defaultdb, @hasaccess, @denylogin
IF (@@fetch_status = -1)
BEGIN
  PRINT 'No login(s) found.'
  CLOSE login_curs
  DEALLOCATE login_curs
END

WHILE (@@fetch_status <> -1)
BEGIN
  IF (@@fetch_status <> -2)
  BEGIN

    IF (@type IN ( 'G', 'U'))
    BEGIN -- NT authenticated account/group

      SET @tmpstr = 'IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT loginname FROM master.dbo.syslogins WHERE name = ''' + @name + ''' AND dbname = ''' + @defaultdb + ''')' + CHAR(13) +
                    'BEGIN TRY' + CHAR(13) +
                    '   CREATE LOGIN ' + QUOTENAME( @name ) + ' FROM WINDOWS WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE = [' + @defaultdb + ']'

    END
    ELSE BEGIN -- SQL Server authentication
        -- obtain password and sid
            SET @PWD_varbinary = CAST( LOGINPROPERTY( @name, 'PasswordHash' ) AS varbinary (256) )
        EXEC sp_hexadecimal @PWD_varbinary, @PWD_string OUT
        EXEC sp_hexadecimal @SID_varbinary,@SID_string OUT

        -- obtain password policy state
        SELECT @is_policy_checked = CASE is_policy_checked WHEN 1 THEN 'ON' WHEN 0 THEN 'OFF' ELSE NULL END FROM sys.sql_logins WHERE name = @name
        SELECT @is_expiration_checked = CASE is_expiration_checked WHEN 1 THEN 'ON' WHEN 0 THEN 'OFF' ELSE NULL END FROM sys.sql_logins WHERE name = @name

            SET @tmpstr = 'IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT loginname FROM master.dbo.syslogins WHERE name = ''' + @name + ''' AND dbname = ''' + @defaultdb + ''')' + CHAR(13) +
                    'BEGIN TRY' + CHAR(13) +
                    '   CREATE LOGIN ' + QUOTENAME( @name ) + ' WITH PASSWORD = ' + @PWD_string + ' HASHED, SID = ' + @SID_string + ', DEFAULT_DATABASE = [' + @defaultdb + ']'

        IF ( @is_policy_checked IS NOT NULL )
        BEGIN
          SET @tmpstr = @tmpstr + ', CHECK_POLICY = ' + @is_policy_checked
        END
        IF ( @is_expiration_checked IS NOT NULL )
        BEGIN
          SET @tmpstr = @tmpstr + ', CHECK_EXPIRATION = ' + @is_expiration_checked
        END
    END
    IF (@denylogin = 1)
    BEGIN -- login is denied access
      SET @tmpstr = @tmpstr + '; DENY CONNECT SQL TO ' + QUOTENAME( @name )
    END
    ELSE IF (@hasaccess = 0)
    BEGIN -- login exists but does not have access
      SET @tmpstr = @tmpstr + '; REVOKE CONNECT SQL TO ' + QUOTENAME( @name )
    END
    IF (@is_disabled = 1)
    BEGIN -- login is disabled
      SET @tmpstr = @tmpstr + '; ALTER LOGIN ' + QUOTENAME( @name ) + ' DISABLE'
    END

    SET @tmpstr = @tmpstr + CHAR(13) + 'END TRY' + CHAR(13) + 'BEGIN CATCH' + CHAR(13) + 'END CATCH'

    SET @message = @message + CHAR(13) + @tmpstr

  END

  FETCH NEXT FROM login_curs INTO @SID_varbinary, @name, @type, @is_disabled, @defaultdb, @hasaccess, @denylogin
   END
CLOSE login_curs
DEALLOCATE login_curs

--removing accessory procedure

DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_hexadecimal]


-- GENERATE SERVER PERMISSIONS
USE [master]

DECLARE @ServerPrincipal SYSNAME
DECLARE @PrincipalType SYSNAME 
DECLARE @PermissionName SYSNAME
DECLARE @StateDesc SYSNAME

SET @message = @message + CHAR(13) + CHAR(13) + '-- CREATE SERVER PERMISSIONS' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(13) +'USE [master]' + CHAR(13)

DECLARE server_permissions_curs CURSOR FOR
SELECT
  [srvprin].[name] [server_principal], 
  [srvprin].[type_desc] [principal_type], 
  [srvperm].[permission_name], 
  [srvperm].[state_desc]  
FROM [sys].[server_permissions] srvperm 
  INNER JOIN [sys].[server_principals] srvprin 
    ON [srvperm].[grantee_principal_id] = [srvprin].[principal_id] 
WHERE [srvprin].[type] IN ('S', 'U', 'G') AND [srvprin].name NOT IN ('sa', 'dbo', 'information_schema', 'sys')
ORDER BY [server_principal], [permission_name]; 

OPEN server_permissions_curs

FETCH NEXT FROM server_permissions_curs INTO @ServerPrincipal, @PrincipalType, @PermissionName, @StateDesc 

WHILE (@@fetch_status <> -1)
BEGIN

    SET @message = @message + CHAR(13) + 'BEGIN TRY' + CHAR(13) + 
                    @StateDesc + N' ' + @PermissionName + N' TO ' + QUOTENAME(@ServerPrincipal) + 
                    + CHAR(13) + 'END TRY' + CHAR(13) + 'BEGIN CATCH' + CHAR(13) + 'END CATCH'

    FETCH NEXT FROM server_permissions_curs INTO @ServerPrincipal, @PrincipalType, @PermissionName, @StateDesc 
END
CLOSE server_permissions_curs
DEALLOCATE server_permissions_curs

--GENERATE USERS AND PERMISSION SCRIPT FOR EVERY DATABASE

SET @message = @message + CHAR(13) + CHAR(13) + N'--ENUMERATE DATABASES'

DECLARE @databases TABLE (
    DatabaseName SYSNAME,
    DatabaseSize INT,
    Remarks SYSNAME NULL
)

INSERT INTO
@databases EXEC sp_databases

DECLARE @DatabaseName SYSNAME


DECLARE database_curs CURSOR FOR
SELECT DatabaseName FROM @databases WHERE DatabaseName IN (N'${DatabaseName}')

OPEN database_curs

FETCH NEXT FROM database_curs INTO @DatabaseName
WHILE (@@fetch_status <> -1)
BEGIN

    SET @tmpStr = 

    N'USE ' + QUOTENAME(@DatabaseName) + '

    DECLARE @tmpstr  NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @messageOut = CHAR(13) + CHAR(13) + ''USE ' + QUOTENAME(@DatabaseName) + ''' + CHAR(13)

    -- GENERATE USERS SCRIPT 

    SET @messageOut = @messageOut + CHAR(13) + ''-- CREATE USERS '' + CHAR(13)

    DECLARE @users TABLE (
    UserName SYSNAME Null,  
    RoleName SYSNAME Null,  
    LoginName SYSNAME Null, 
    DefDBName SYSNAME Null, 
    DefSchemaName SYSNAME Null, 
    UserID INT Null,    
    [SID] varbinary(85) Null
    )

    INSERT INTO
    @users   EXEC sp_helpuser

    DECLARE @UserName SYSNAME
    DECLARE @LoginName SYSNAME 
    DECLARE @DefSchemaName SYSNAME

    DECLARE user_curs CURSOR FOR
    SELECT UserName, LoginName, DefSchemaName FROM @users

    OPEN user_curs

    FETCH NEXT FROM user_curs INTO @UserName, @LoginName, @DefSchemaName
    WHILE (@@fetch_status <> -1)
    BEGIN

        SET @messageOut = @messageOut + CHAR(13) + 
                        ''IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.database_principals WHERE name = N''''''+ @UserName +'''''')''
                        + CHAR(13) + ''BEGIN TRY'' + CHAR(13) + 
                        ''  CREATE USER '' + QUOTENAME(@UserName)

        IF (@LoginName IS NOT NULL)
            SET @messageOut = @messageOut + '' FOR LOGIN '' + QUOTENAME(@LoginName)
        ELSE
            SET @messageOut = @messageOut + '' WITHOUT LOGIN''  

        IF (@DefSchemaName IS NOT NULL)
            SET @messageOut = @messageOut + '' WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = ''  + QUOTENAME(@DefSchemaName)

        SET @messageOut = @messageOut + CHAR(13) + ''END TRY'' + CHAR(13) + ''BEGIN CATCH'' + CHAR(13) + ''END CATCH''

        FETCH NEXT FROM user_curs INTO @UserName, @LoginName, @DefSchemaName
    END
    CLOSE user_curs
    DEALLOCATE user_curs

    -- GENERATE ROLES

    SET @messageOut = @messageOut + CHAR(13) + CHAR(13) + ''-- CREATE ROLES '' + CHAR(13)

    SELECT @messageOut = @messageOut + CHAR(13) + ''BEGIN TRY'' + CHAR(13) + 
                        N''EXEC sp_addrolemember N''''''+ rp.name +'''''', N''''''+ mp.name +''''''''
                        + CHAR(13) + ''END TRY'' + CHAR(13) + ''BEGIN CATCH'' + CHAR(13) + ''END CATCH''
    FROM sys.database_role_members drm
    join sys.database_principals rp ON (drm.role_principal_id = rp.principal_id)
    join sys.database_principals mp ON (drm.member_principal_id = mp.principal_id)
    WHERE mp.name NOT IN (N''dbo'')


    -- GENERATE PERMISSIONS

    SET @messageOut = @messageOut + CHAR(13) + CHAR(13) + ''-- CREATE PERMISSIONS '' + CHAR(13)

    SELECT @messageOut = @messageOut + CHAR(13) + ''BEGIN TRY'' + CHAR(13) + 
                        ''  GRANT '' + dp.permission_name collate latin1_general_cs_as +
                        '' ON '' + QUOTENAME(s.name) + ''.'' + QUOTENAME(o.name) + '' TO '' + QUOTENAME(dpr.name)  +
                        + CHAR(13) + ''END TRY'' + CHAR(13) + ''BEGIN CATCH'' + CHAR(13) + ''END CATCH''
    FROM sys.database_permissions AS dp
    INNER JOIN sys.objects AS o ON dp.major_id=o.object_id
    INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s ON o.schema_id = s.schema_id
    INNER JOIN sys.database_principals AS dpr ON dp.grantee_principal_id=dpr.principal_id
    WHERE dpr.name NOT IN (''public'',''guest'')'

    EXECUTE sp_executesql @tmpStr, N'@messageOut NVARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT', @messageOut = @tmpstr OUTPUT

    SET @message = @message + @tmpStr

    FETCH NEXT FROM database_curs INTO @DatabaseName
END
CLOSE database_curs
DEALLOCATE database_curs

SELECT @message
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @DBRoleName varchar(40) = 'yourUserName'
SELECT 'GRANT ' + dbprm.permission_name + ' ON ' + OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(major_id) + '.' + OBJECT_NAME(major_id) + ' TO ' + dbrol.name + char(13) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS
from sys.database_permissions dbprm
join sys.database_principals dbrol on
dbprm.grantee_principal_id = dbrol.principal_id
where dbrol.name = @DBRoleName
```

http://www.sqlserver-dba.com/2014/10/how-to-script-database-role-permissions-and-securables.html

I found this to be an excellent solution for generating a script to replicate access between environments