# SQL Server 2005 Logins, Securables, Roles and Permissions Backup

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Our non production servers have information refreshed into them on a regular basis from production.  The way this is done is to do a full backup of production, then restore it onto the non-production SQL Server. This has the undesired effect of overwriting all of the permissions for users.

I have been trying to find a method to pull those permissions out of the database in the form of a script. That way when the database is refreshed, I can run the script against the newly refreshed database and restore the permissions.

I tried to find the data in sys.database_principals and sys.database_permissions, but my SQL-fu isn't good enough to make this data into something usable.

What's the best method to get this data out?

Comment: whats wrong with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987190/scripting-sql-server-permissions?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

K. Brian Kelley has a pretty good script for this at [SQLServerCentral](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/brian_kelley/2009/08/28/quick-2005-2008-script-to-export-permissions/).

You can also try some of the "Related" links on the right of this page.

Comment: Yup, that was just what I needed. I cant believe I wasn't able to find that myself.  Thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Heres another one that works quiet similar but supports colum level permissions. The output works, but has to be improved for more complex databases. So, just to give you the idea:

```
SELECT 'GRANT ' + database_permissions.permission_name + ' ON ' +
    CASE database_permissions.class_desc
        WHEN 'SCHEMA' THEN schema_name(major_id)
        WHEN 'OBJECT_OR_COLUMN' THEN
            CASE WHEN minor_id = 0 THEN object_name(major_id) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS_KS_WS
            ELSE (SELECT object_name(object_id) + ' ('+ name + ')'
                  FROM sys.columns 
                  WHERE object_id = database_permissions.major_id 
                  AND column_id = database_permissions.minor_id) end
        ELSE 'other' 
    END + 
    ' TO ' + database_principals.name COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS_KS_WS
FROM sys.database_permissions
JOIN sys.database_principals
ON database_permissions.grantee_principal_id = database_principals.principal_id
LEFT JOIN sys.objects -- consider schemas
ON objects.object_id = database_permissions.major_id
WHERE database_permissions.major_id > 0
AND permission_name in ('SELECT','INSERT','UPDATE','DELETE')
```